# Explanation requested for a specific regxp

Tags: php, regex

I have an issue **understanding the "+" sign.**

Here is my example:

```
$array = array("123 Main St.");

$match = preg_grep("%^\d{1,5}\s[A-Za-z.]+\s[A-Za-z.]{2,7}$%",$array);

foreach($match as $value) {
    echo "<pre>" .$value . "<br>";
}
```

So basically this totally works, but I don't understand the "+" sign's job.  If I remove it, it does not work.

Comment: Just one or more characters like the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` is equal to `{1,}` meaning *1 or more*

Comment: so you are saying that [a-z]+   and   [a-z]{1,}  is the same?

Comment: Yes. `{1,}` is so common they made a special character for it. Like `*` which means `{0,}` _0 or more_

Comment: i need to wait 9 mins before i can close the question.  Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 3):

`+` in regex is to match 1 or more of preceding group OR pattern.

In your example: `[A-Za-z.]+` will match 1 OR more of English alphabets (case insensitive) OR a literal dot.

[**Read more about regular expressions**](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: Yes and suggest bookmarking that link as well. AN extremely good reference on regex.

Comment: Yea i will do that.  My first hour with regxp today, and i can do a regxp vs an email.  I hope i will learn most of it very fast, atleast i find it extremly amuzing ;)

Answer (score 1):

`+` means at least one or more occurrences of the expression.

In your case `[A-Za-z.]+` means there shall be at least a single alphabet or a dot.